# Inject doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

Why doesn't this line of code work?

```
['fdfsd','gfdhgf'].inject(Hash.new){|sum,e| sum[e] = e}
```

Using ruby-1.9.2-p180, got `IndexError: string not matched`

---

#### Solved

```
['fdfsd','gfdhgf'].inject(Hash.new){|sum,e| sum[e] = e; sum}
```

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.9 there's also `each_with_object`:

```
>> ['fdfsd','gfdhgf'].each_with_object(Hash.new){|e,sum| sum[e] = e}
=> {"fdfsd"=>"fdfsd", "gfdhgf"=>"gfdhgf"}
```

Note that compared to `inject` the block arguments are reversed and that you don't have to explicitly return the accumulator. In this specific case I'd go with J-_-L's answer by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Different approach with same effect:

```
a = ['fdfsd','gfdhgf']
Hash[a.zip(a)]
```